# Double count a column based on another column for join table

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is difficult to explain in the title, but I have a column that's a join table, and I'd like to count the number of books a character has appeared in based the `type` of book.

So if `cb.type = 2`, then I want `count(cb.id) + 1` if that makes sense. Otherwise for all other types, just count it normally with `count(cb.id)`.

```
  SELECT
   CASE
     WHEN cb.type = 2 THEN count(cb.id) + 1
     ELSE count(cb.id)
   END AS book_count,
   c.*
  FROM characters c
         INNER JOIN character_books cb ON cb.character_id = c.id
  GROUP BY c.id, cb.type
  ORDER BY book_count DESC
```

The above query does not work because I have to group by `c.id, cb.type`, and so I'm not getting the total number of books the character has appeared in.

Now without considering the `cb.type`, the query would look like this:

```
  SELECT count(cb.id) AS book_count, c.*
  FROM characters c
         INNER JOIN character_books cb ON cb.character_id = c.id
  GROUP BY c.id
  ORDER BY book_count DESC
```

However, if the column `cb.type = 2` (which is actually a bitwise column, just using the number `2` here for simplicity), then we should be adding an additional count to `book_count`.

How would I make this happen?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  `SELECT COUNT(*)` with `GROUP BY` usually does not make sense (unless you really know what you are doing).

Comment: Is there a better way to count how many books each character has appeared in without using a group by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation.  I think you want:

```
SELECT c.id, 
       SUM(CASE cb.type = 2 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END) as book_count
FROM characters c INNER JOIN
     character_books cb
     ON cb.character_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY book_count DESC;
```